# Custom SSIS task detect connection manager changed

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I my custom SSIS Task I set the normal variables like this

```
designTimeInstance.SetComponentProperty("MaxRows", tbMaxRows.Text);
```

If I over ride SetComponentProperty I can detect that one of the properties was changed.

```
 public override IDTSCustomProperty100 SetComponentProperty(string propertyName, object propertyValue)
        {
            var setProperty = base.SetComponentProperty(propertyName, propertyValue);
            propertiesChanged = true;
            return setProperty;
        }
```

My problem / question is.   When setting the connection manager we don't call SetComponentProperty we assign it directly to the RuntimeConnectionCollection.  How can I detect then that it was changed?

```
 componentMetaData.RuntimeConnectionCollection[0].ConnectionManagerID = cm.ID;
 componentMetaData.RuntimeConnectionCollection[0].ConnectionManager = DtsConvert.GetExtendedInterface(cm);
```